# OData 8 / ASP.NET Core 7 MVC : routing by convention - only the Delete method not creating an endpoint

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, odata, asp.net-core-7.0

Controller:

```cs
public class HomeController : ODataController
{
    private readonly TestDbContext _context;
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, TestDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _context = dbContext;
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Home>> Get()
    {
        var items = _context.Home.Include(o => o.Option).Take(50).ToList<Home>();
        return items;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Home HttpBody)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var option in HttpBody.Option)
            {
                var currentOptions = _context.Option.Local
                                             .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == option.Id); 
                if (currentOptions != null)
                {
                    option.Id = currentOptions.Id;
                }
                else 
                {
                    _context.Attach(option);
                }
            }

            _context.Home.Add(HttpBody);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Ok();
        }
        else
        { 
            return BadRequest(); 
        }
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public ActionResult Delete([FromRoute] Guid id)
    {
            _context.Home.Remove(new Home()
            {
                Id = id,
            });
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return NoContent();
    }
}
```

Relevant `Program.cs`:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
modelBuilder.EntitySet<Home>("Home");

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(options => 
    options.Select().EnableQueryFeatures().AddRouteComponents(
    routePrefix: "api",
    model: modelBuilder.GetEdmModel())

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());

app.Run();
);
```

When I debug, I can query `{host}/$odata` and see `GET,POST,PATCH` methods from above, but not `DELETE`.

I have tried adding and removing `[HttpDelete]` attribute; the other methods function fine with or without their respective attributes.

I've tried replacing `app.MapControllerRoute(...)` with `app.UseEndpoints` as shown above.

When `MapControllerRoute` is used, the 'Delete' method is returned from `{host}/$odata` as non-odata methods with the route template itself as their route. Otherwise, they are omitted from results.

I've tried `[ODataAttributeRouting]` and `[ODataRouteComponent]` attributes for both the controller and the method but to no luck either.

I'm looking at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/tutorials/basic-crud?tabs=net60%2Cvisual-studio-2022%2Cvisual-studio%2Cvs2022) tutorial and it seems about the same.

Comment: First of all are you having this scenario in deployment environment or even in local? In addition to this, whats your server mode? classic or Integrated? Have you tried attribute routing `[AcceptVerbs("DELETE")]` instead of OData routing convention

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the name of the parameters passed to any functions with the [FromRoute] attribute must conform with OData routing conventions. In this case, changing `Delete([FromRoute] Guid id)` to `Delete([FromRoute] Guid key)` does the trick